# Deploy iso through e.g. dd using pxe

Tags: deployment, automated-install

Our current means of deploying machines is to mirror the nvme drive from a master drive before installing it in a PC.

We are deploying windows on machines that will go to customers. As such, aad (and therefore autopilot) are out of the question.

I'd like to be able to deploy a machine after the nvme has been fitted, and was therefore looking at pxe boot.

What are my options?
I have tried netboot.xyz, but not worked out how to use that to write an iso or image to a disk.
I've looked into autopilot, but can't find any guides that don't use domains.

Comment: Have you looked into using Clonezilla? All of these imaging solutions have one drawback - your licensing status would depend on your license key type, but you can alleviate it with scripting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After being pointed to Clonezilla Live by Peter Zhabin, I ran into a discussion mentioning https://fogproject.org/. I've turned my NVME drives into virtual machines, and registered those by MAC address. FOG can now issue a command to re-image those, allowing me to easily update my images.

Changing one setting makes PCs in the network, that boot into PXE mode, automatically go to a screen which allows me to select which image needs to be deployed.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Serva](https://www.vercot.com/%7Eserva/an/WindowsPXE1.html). Single exe PXE server that allows you to either deploy Install images or just capture your golden image and deploy it to as many PCs you want on a network